# Cleaning up the iPhone simulator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there a straightforward way to clean up the directory where xcode deploys an app when building for the iPhone simulator?  I have a sqlite database that gets copied into the Documents folder on startup if necessary. The problem is that I might change my schema, but the new database won't get copied, because one already exists.

Ideally, every time I build, it would nuke the previous contents. Is this possible, or do I have to manually do it?

Comment: Does the simulator support AppleScript?

Comment: Yes it does. I've written an AppleScript to iterate through all of the iOS simulators for each device and OS version and reset their Contents & Settings: https://github.com/michaelpatzer/ResetAllSimulators

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The simulator installs apps into:

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications"
```

Also check:

```
"$HOME/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices"
```

The GUID files and directories match up to the simulator's installed apps.

Manually delete all those files/directories to remove all applications from the simulator.

I know there is some way to add scripts to the build process in XCode.

Also it looks as if XCode changes the GUID it uses each build (the directory where my app sits changes between builds in XCode), so trying to delete the same directory all the time won't work. If you are only working on one app at a time then clearing out the entire directory would be an option.

Comment: Be sure to check out @idStar's answer down below.  It has updated information regarding Lion/Xcode4 and a nice little script to help automate things.

Comment: I was testing adding/removing calendar subscriptions. On a real device, you can remove a calendar subscription in Settings > Accounts but this menu does not exist on iOS Simulator and I did not want to reset the whole simulator. So I ended up locally versioning my _Device_ folder with git and perform a `git reset HEAD --hard && git clean -f` to remove a calendar subscription after I added it.

Answer (score 136):

From Apples Dev Resources:

> To set the user content and settings of the simulator to their factory state and remove the applications you  have installed, choose
> **Device > Erase All Content and Settings**.

*(On older versions: iPhone Simulator > Reset Content and Settings.)*

Comment: This one does not seem to clean the SQLite

Comment: this doesn't clear the cache of the browser for instance

Comment: Now this setting is located in `Hardware > Reset Content and Settings`

Comment: This setting is now located in `Device > Erase All Content and Settings`

Answer (score 22):

The way I do this is to simply click and hold on the icon for my app in the simulator--then when it starts to wiggle click the black and white (x). A message will pop up asking whether you really want to delete and you just click yes. The next time you build and deploy your app it will use the new sqlite db without a hitch and you don't have to go muck around in the filesystem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work - it doesn't ACTUALLY delete data from the simulator?

Comment: My mistake - this works fine (confirmed by reading the directory in the accepted answer. I'd just forgotten Apple's user-unfriendly design of NSUserDefaults (unset values aren't reported by any sensible manner)

Comment: @quadelirus, I think your answer is the most appropriate in this situation.

Comment: This is what exactly i did, but i'm not sure how to close the app which has open already in simulator. Until unless I close the app, i could't get control on simulator.

Comment: @WannaCoffee See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519799/ios-simulator-how-to-close-an-app

Comment: Thanks., this comment actually helps.!! The shortcut is ⌘+⇧+H, but you need to hit H twice in a row for it to simulate the double press that shows the apps.

Answer (score 12):

After iOS 5 on Mac OS X Lion, you can try:

1. Create a script called `RemoveSimulatorApps.command` that contains:

   ```
   rm -rf "$HOME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/*"
   ```
2. Save this script to a directory in your `PATH`.
3. Make the file executable, such as:

   ```
   chmod +x RemoveSimulatorApps.command
   ```

### Assumptions

- You may want to invoke this from a keyboard favorites buttons, such as on a Logitech or Microsoft keyboard with programmable keys (hence, saving it as a .command file instead of say, .sh)
- You are okay with blowing away everything in the iOS simulator (ideal if you're just actively working on one app)
- All the notes from others apply about being a good upgradable app etc. (I personally found this useful nonetheless b/c I have development mode switches that reload a database in a specific state I was trying to do some consistent robustness/error handling on)

Comment: This one works perfectly, just remember to add your right IOS version into the path :)

Comment: Would it makes sense to add ~ instead of absolute path?

Answer (score 8):

it may be overkill but..

you can also use the menu and 'Reset Content and Settings...'

Answer (score 8):

for Xcode >= 6

```
xcrun simctl list | grep -oh '[A-Z0-9]\{8\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{12\}' | xargs -n1 xcrun simctl erase
```

Answer (score 7):

What you are really trying to do is to clear out your database, if you've changed the schema.  One way to do this, and it would make you happier in the long run when you start shipping version 2.0, 3.0, etc. of your app, is to check the version of your sqlite table, and if it has changed, then discard the old file and use the one in your bundle.

Finding a way to clean up the Simulator won't help the real world problem of how to clean up a customer's iPhone when you ship a new version with a new schema.

For extra points, after determining that you have encountered an old schema, you may want to   copy the new database over without destroying the old one, and load any interesting data out of the old database, into the new one.  Then blow away the old database.  That way you can preserve your user's additions to the database.

Comment: In general, I agree with you when you are talking about release upgrades, but in the midst of development of any particular version, this is far more overhead than is necessary. Database schema can change on a per-build basis, and needing to write conversion code for every build is just wrong.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Xcode 9 -> ***Menubar*** -> ***Hardware*** -> ***Erase All Content and Settings***

[image: Xcode -> Hardware -> Erase All Content and Settings]

Answer (score 6):

The following command in the terminal will wipe all of your simulators as if you had just installed them.

$`xcrun simctl erase all`

Just close simulators before you run it.

Answer (score 5):

As of Xcode 6, you can do this from the command line with:
xcrun simctl erase

Also, the iOS Simulator app (both the Xcode 6 version and older versions) has a menu item called "Reset Content and Settings" that can be used to erase the currently booted device.

Comment: but it can be executed on each build automatically? for example for tests?

Comment: Assuming you are doing your tests using a script, you could certainly just add 'xcrun simctl erase <UDID>' to that script where appropriate...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 5):

This works with Xcode 6:

```
xcrun simctl list | grep -oh '[A-Z0-9]\{8\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{12\}' | xargs -I{} xcrun simctl erase {}
```

For .bash_profile

```
alias cleansim="xcrun simctl list | grep -oh '[A-Z0-9]\{8\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{4\}-[A-Z0-9]\{12\}' | xargs -I{} xcrun simctl erase {}"
```

Answer (score 4):

As of Xcode 6:

`xcrun simctl erase <sim udid>` <- resets the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

**Clear Xcode Cache;**

> Command+Option+Shift+K
>
> Command+Shift+K

*(Use both of them because they have different functionality)*

**Clear Derived Data content ;**

> Menu Bar -> Window -> Organizer -> Projects -> Select Your Project

*Right Pane shows the name of folder and also delete button at the right side allows you to delete all derived data contents.*

**Clear Simulator Cache;**

> Menu Bar -> iOS Simulator -> Reset Contents And Settings

Answer (score 1):

As I was explaining in a comment under the [validated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/692084/2003763):

I was testing adding and removing calendar subscriptions. On a real device, you can remove a calendar subscription in *Settings*, *Accounts* but this menu does not exist in iOS Simulator and I did not want to reset the whole simulator.

So I ended up **locally** versioning my *Device* folder with git and perform the following commands to remove a calendar subscription after I added it:

```
$ git reset HEAD --hard
$ git clean -f
```

So the steps are:

1. Install your application on the iOS Simulator and do what you have to do
2. Identify your device in `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/` and do a `cd` to it, then `git init` to create a git repository
3. Once you want to save the state, perform `git commit -a "Message"`
4. Do whatever changes the settings (ex: adding a calendar subscription) and perform your tests
5. Shutdown the simulator
6. Do `git reset --hard HEAD`
7. Start the simulator, all changes done after `git commit` are gone.

Answer (score 1):

In XCode, go to the Window menu option, select Devices and then you can just delete the ones you no longer need.

Answer (score 0):

**For Xcode <= 5**

I added the following to my `~/.bash_profile`

```
alias cleansim='rm -r ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/5.1/Applications/*'
```

It just nukes all of the apps on the sim.

Comment: This is no longer applicable with Xcode 6 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Using Xcode 14.1 and an iphone14 simulator I deleted the app as I would on an iPhone. This deletes all data from the app. When I rebuilt, and all the data in the Documents folder was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for Xcode 14 in Mac OS Ventura 13

Open your simulator. You can do in your terminal: `open -a simulator`

Then just `Device` -> `Erase All Content and Settings...`

[image]