# Sqlite doesn't seem to like my delete statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I've got the following iphone code, which seems to be failing:

```
sqlite3_stmt *dbps;
NSString *sql = @"delete from days where day=?1;insert into days(disabled,recipe_id,day) values(?2,?3,?1)";
int rc = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql.UTF8String, -1, &dbps, NULL);
...
```

The 'rc' return code is 1, meaning SQLITE_ERROR (SQL error or missing database, according to the sqlite site). Not sure what i've done wrong? The database 'db' is indeed open, and other queries seem to work fine.

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: why can't you issue an update statement rather than a delete/insert?  do you have multiple days with the same day_id?

Comment: I know it's kludgey, but i'm doing the delete/insert because sometimes there is nothing in the table for that day, and i don't want to have to check first then choose between update/insert.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the insert statement from your string. It is not compiled anyway since `sqlite3_prepare_v2` will "only compile the first statement in `zSql`."

Perhaps you should use a trigger to do your (optional) delete, or use `insert or replace`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have copied the database in Documents directory before opening it? iPhone OS only allow write permissions in documents directory. Here is the code for copying database to Documents directory -

```
//function to copy database in Documents dir.

    -(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{
        // Check if the SQL database has already been saved to the users phone, if not then copy it over
        BOOL success;

    // Create a FileManager object, we will use this to check the status
    // of the database and to copy it over if required
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Check if the database has already been created in the users filesystem
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    // If the database already exists then return without doing anything
    if(success) return;

    // If not then proceed to copy the database from the application to the users filesystem

    // Get the path to the database in the application package
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    // Copy the database from the package to the users filesystem
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];


  }


// open the database and fire the delete query...


    sqlite3 *database;
    NSString *sqlStatement = @"";



    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
            NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
    [serlf checkAndCreateDatabase];



    if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {

// here you can fire the delete query...
    }
```

Comment: Yes, i thought of that, i've made sure that it's copied to the documents. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me, i just had an old copy of the schema in my Documents folder, which didn't have the 'days' table in it. So i followed the instructions here: [Cleaning up the iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692064/cleaning-up-the-iphone-simulator), and then it copied the new schema over, and it started working again.

Thanks for the help guys.