# automate installation + running of iphone app in simulator outside of xcode

Tags: iphone, automation, build-automation, simulator

I'd like to install + run my app built outside of xcode (through xcodebuild) through a similar sort of command line tool.  How could I get it on the simulator?

I've looked at a few related posts:

[Where does the iPhone Simulator store its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108076/where-does-the-iphone-simulator-store-its-data)
[Cleaning up the iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692064/cleaning-up-the-iphone-simulator)

None of these posts describe what that UUID is, nor what the other files are in that directory.

So how I could I replicate XCode's installation + starting the app through a command line tool?

Comment: This might be relavant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172688/how-does-jetbrains-appcode-launch-the-ios-simulator