# Cannot add a new item in the keychain. Error code: -25243. in ADAL iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure, adal

I have integrated microsoft's [ADAL library for iOS](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc) in my iOS objective C project. I authenticated the azure's proxy share point site and keep the app in idle state for more than an hour. After I activate the app and click on any hyper-link I get the following error

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted" UserInfo=0x1452d320 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://login.windows.net/*someToken*/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=319ef615-4cb2-4e65-97bd-69a5fed167a4&scope=openid&nonce=90069b91-cacd-40a1-ae3e-13fbc0e50dff&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fintranetspqa.xyz.com%2fpages%2ffeed.aspx&state=AppProxyState%3a%7b%22IsMsofba%22%3afalse%2c%22OriginalQuery%22%3a%22%22%7d, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://login.windows.net/*someToken*/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token&client_id=319ef615-4cb2-4e65-97bd-69a5fed167a4&scope=openid&nonce=90069b91-cacd-40a1-ae3e-13fbc0e50dff&response_mode=form_post&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fintranetspqa.xyz.com%2fpages%2ffeed.aspx&state=AppProxyState%3a%7b%22IsMsofba%22%3afalse%2c%22OriginalQuery%22%3a
```

followed by

```
Cannot add a new item in the keychain. Error code: -25243. Attributes: {
    acct = cHJhcGF0aWxAZXF1aW5peC5jb20;
    svce = "MSOpenTech.ADAL.1|aHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi5taWNyb3NvZnRvbmxpbmUuY29tLzcyYWRiMjcxLTJmYzctNGFmZS1hNWVlLTlkZTZhNTlmNmJmYg|CC3513A0-0E69-4B4D-97FC-DFB6C91EE132|YzczOWU0ZmItNTE1ZC00N2JhLWIzOGMtZTk2MjZjOGRhODAy";
}. ErrorCode: 11.
2015-09-08 16:41:36.154 ProjectName[32578:3728597] ADALiOS [2015-09-08 11:11:36 - C739E4FB-515D-47BA-B38C-E9626C8DA802] ERROR: Error raised: 11. Additional Information: Domain: ADAuthenticationErrorDomain ProtocolCode:(null) Details:Cannot add a new item in the keychain. Error code: -25243. Attributes: {
    acct = cHJhcGF0aWxAZXF1aW5peC5jb20;
    svce = "MSOpenTech.ADAL.1|aHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi5taWNyb3NvZnRvbmxpbmUuY29tLzcyYWRiMjcxLTJmYzctNGFmZS1hNWVlLTlkZTZhNTlmNmJmYg|MzE5ZWY2MTUtNGNiMi00ZTY1LTk3YmQtNjlhNWZlZDE2N2E0|YzczOWU0ZmItNTE1ZC00N2JhLWIzOGMtZTk2MjZjOGRhODAy";
}. ErrorCode: 11.
```

Ignore *some token* and *xyz* in above urls.

I have implemented the required methods as mentioned in [ADAL github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-objc).
I referred [ADAL forum](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-iOS/issues/83) and following links
[iOS Keychain SecItemAdd returns -25243](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989258/ios-keychain-secitemadd-returns-25243) and 
[How to share keychain data between iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115744/how-to-share-keychain-data-between-ios-applications)

I have two questions that might solve this issue : 1. If this is keychain sharing issue, what changes shall I make in project.entitlements file? 2. If I have to call refresh token to keep the user authenticated, how shall I call it using ADAL as I referred [this link](http://www.hasaltaiar.com.au/how-to-best-handle-aad-access-tokens-in-native-mobile-apps/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that when you go to use the refresh token you fail as you don't have entitlements for the iOS keychain of the app that contains the refresh token. Let's try a few things:

1. Can you make sure that you are using the **"Capabilities" tab** of your Target for your iOS app and that it is the same across all your applications?

[image: Here you should see that both items are checked "added to entitlements and added to the app ID]

2. Make sure you have **setSharedKeychainGroup:** set in ADAL. This tells ADAL what keychain group you want to use for shared SSO.

From the Header file:

`/*! The name of the keychain group to be used if sharing of cache between applications
 is desired. Can be nil. The property sets the appropriate value of defaultTokenCacheStore
 object. See apple's documentation for keychain groups: such groups require certain
 entitlements to be set by the applications. Additionally, access to the items in this group
 is only given to the applications from the same vendor. If this property is not set, the behavior
 will depend on the values in the entitlements file (if such exists) and may not result in token
 sharing. The property has no effect if other cache mechanisms are used (non-keychain). */
@property (getter = getSharedCacheKeychainGroup, setter = setSharedCacheKeychainGroup:) NSString* sharedCacheKeychainGroup;`

Comment: and to add what you answered, you have to switch the developer account to "None", then switch back to your developer account which has keychain sharing enabled again. Xcode needs to be refreshed and configured with your developer account