# How to delete the aging APP from ios?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-simulator

I want to delete some of my old App's (not every one) in my **iphone Simulator**.

How can i delete them? If **reset** is the only option then it will delete all the apps and not only the ones i specify. Or is there any option to select the app's to be deleted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cleaning up the iPhone simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/692064/cleaning-up-the-iphone-simulator)

Comment: through follow diriction -->iPhone Simulator/4.2(or)5.0(or)anything else/Applications   (Delete wat u want)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete an app in the simulator in the same manner as on a device, hold down on the app icon for a few seconds and tap the "x".

You can also remove the App data from within the Finder under ~/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications (Or whatever version of the simulator you are running.)