# iOS Simulator keeps asking for an app to simulate

Tags: ios-simulator

I only use the iOS simulator for testing websites, not actual apps.  Today I opened it up and it keeps asking me for an app for it to simulate.  If I click cancel, it just quits the simulator.

I've tried deleting preference files, but I'm just not familiar enough with the simulator to know what's going on.  How can I just get this back to normal, or satisfy this dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try the menu

iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

This would clean your simulator storage.

**Update**

According to this link, [Cleaning up the iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692064/cleaning-up-the-iphone-simulator)

move to path

`/Users/<username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/{6.0 / 6.1}`

You could try to clean it manually

Comment: I would if I could get to the menu. As soon as I open the simulator, this dialog pops up. If I click `cancel` then it quits.

Comment: You could try to clean it yourself. Please take a look at my update :)