# How can you debug opening universal links from a cold start?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-links

Universal links & deep links works when I am already debugging the app.

However I can't test opening a link from a cold start.  I.e. Tapping on a link on safari when the app is not running.

I cant see how to attach the debugger if Xcode does not launch the app itself.

I assumed the answer would be create a custom scheme, but I can't see any options to open the app with web link.

[image: scheme options]

Comment: Alex has the answer, you should accept his

Answer (score 11):

You should use the **Wait for executable to be launched** configuration option. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521276/ios-how-to-debug-freshly-launching-an-app-from-a-url) for instructions.