# iOS simulator : How can I see the background apps?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios9, ios10, simulator

How can I see the background apps on iOS simulator ?
What is the keyboard shortcut for it or what I have to select from the simulator menu ?

Comment: What does "check the background apps" even mean? And what does this have to do with _programming_?

Comment: I try to see them. And then I will select and will close by selecting, just like on iPhone.

Comment: So do it just the same way you do it on the device: click the Home button twice. You can do that with Command-Shift-H (twice).

Comment: @matt Okey you should post this as a reply and I will approve it.

Comment: You should delete the question. It's not appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Comment: But I asked a similar question like this http://stackoverflow.com/q/18519799/1136253 and thats a popular question.

Comment: True enough. In fact, since that question is about how to click Home, and  _this_ question is about how to click Home twice, one might well contend that they are the _same_ question. All the more reason to delete _this_ one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To see background apps on simulator you should just click on Command-Shift-H 2 times and you can see all your background apps.