# exit app from simulator in ios without clicking "stop the running application" from Xcode and exit()

Tags: ios, xcode

how to close a running app and return to simulator without programmatically writing exit() and also without stoping the running application from Xcode...is there any other way?

Comment: command + h  for return to home page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios simulator: how to close an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519799/ios-simulator-how-to-close-an-app)

Comment: Press Cmd(Command) + Shift + H

Answer (score 0):

Press Cmd(Command) + Shift + H + H(Twice H) it will ope multitasking bar and you can exit app like in device.