# Reliable way to close an app on the iPhone Simulator while working with React Native

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519799/ios-simulator-how-to-close-an-app) points out hitting cmd+shift+H twice or hitting the home button twice should open the app carousel and swiping up should close an app.

Yet I found myself pressing it multiple times and the carousel only shows up about half of the times. Other times 5 consecutive presses brings it up. Sometimes it just goes to the home screen and only works if I go inside the app again and do it from there. I wonder, is there a reliable way to go about it except resorting to this voodoo? ;-)

I am working with [react-native storybook](https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/tree/master/app/react-native) if it holds any significance:

```
npm run storybook
```

I am working on iPhone 6 plus simulator so the iPhone X simulator swipe up is less of an option for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the terminal:**

```
xcrun simctl terminate [device name] [bundle id]
```

For example:

```
xcrun simctl terminate "iPhone 8 Plus" org.reactjs.native.example.layout"
```

or

**Add to the package.json:**

```
"close": "xcrun simctl terminate \"iPhone 8 Plus\" org.reactjs.native.example.layout",
```

and run:

```
npm run close
```